# Gitlab Ci :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses error

Tags: android, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am trying to implement continues integration in my android project. But i could not run asssembleDebug successfully.

.gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
    image: openjdk:8-jdk

    variables:
      ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "28"
      ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "28.0.3"
      ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS:   "4333796"

    before_script:
      - apt-get --quiet update --yes
      - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
      - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
      - unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
      - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
      - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" >/dev/null
      - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
      - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
      - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
      - chmod +x ./gradlew
      # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
      - set +o pipefail
      - yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
      - set -o pipefail

    stages:
      - build
      - test

    lintDebug:
      stage: build
      script:
        - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :app:lintDebug -PbuildDir=lint

    assembleDebug:
      stage: build
      script:
        - ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace
      artifacts:
        paths:
          - app/build/outputs/

    debugTests:
      stage: test
      script:
        - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :app:testDebug
```

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: "de.mannodermaus.android-junit5"


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appname"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // 2) Connect JUnit 5 to the runner
        testInstrumentationRunnerArgument "runnerBuilder", "de.mannodermaus.junit5.AndroidJUnit5Builder"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility java_version
        targetCompatibility java_version
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude "META-INF/LICENSE*"
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'

    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${dagger_version}"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:${firebase_version}"


    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofit_version}"


    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:${glide_version}"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:${glide_version}"


    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'


    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2")



}
```

And error logs.

https://storage.googleapis.com/gitlab-gprd-artifacts/e0/25/e02564e9e68f88fc6032121b033518cd7c1654021787247bea365855ff3a020b/2019_06_11/228909266/237037401/job.log?response-content-type=text%2Fplain%3B%20charset%3Dutf-8&response-content-disposition=inline&GoogleAccessId=gitlab-object-storage-prd@gitlab-production.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Signature=HGcZ7xzOAGHqWdf5WX8wke5Q1YLlM24cQ3dPydAPBaE9T2BCmAVdNbTydWj9%0AeinNdtdqURaDT50WEru1X0ycLYycVog9aMhflJ1Y8a4WF0EjsWZp0JMXnDXH%0AOHeotOln9S0fVxlVOVRji0e2ztvzsfhULrr2gimilB5hF0XNbh%2BVT103D0wW%0A5TPf4RdLyOnsv1CBlH%2Fd1L2qoUrL5TiNCxJ8JcSX5dQQyqh13QuIQnTCfbD5%0AmCGUL%2BUeZGjW5sNh4PTq19KAFZxDwiezVwCw0O%2B9Yr1M4YPONq2xf8EsboL6%0A91FasOBvXsEETp162l7H%2BJWwyKokAPVPnnxEFqm8Qw%3D%3D&Expires=1560247386

Any idea that where the problem is ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I added gradle.properties to .gitigntore which contains

```
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
```

After remove gradle.properties file from .gitignore fixed the problem.